# Value type and reference type in Swift

Tags: swift

As per the apple documentation **String** is a Struct (value type) and **NSString** is Class (Reference type). Reference type means if we change the value of reference it will reflect in the original value too.
check the below code.

Can anyone explain me what will be the output of below code and why?

```
import UIKit

var str:NSString = "Hello, playground"

var newStr = str

newStr = "hello"

print(str)
print(newStr)
```

According to me both str and newStr should print **hello** as they are reference type, but the output is

> Hello, playground
>
> hello

Comment: `newStr = "hello"` assigns `newStr` as a reference to a different constant string. `str` still refers to the original string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `NSString` is immutable, so although it is a reference type, it cannot be changed.

Now, when you say `var str:NSString = "Hello, playground"` you are setting `str` as a reference to a constant string "Hello, playground".

You then have `var newStr = str`, so `newStr` and `str` will both refer to the same constant string.

Finally you have `newStr = "hello"`, so `newStr` now refers to a different constant string.  At no time did you  modify the original constant string "Hello, playground", and indeed you can't since it is both a constant and an immutable class.

If, however, you use an `NSMutableString` and write:

```
var str:NSMutableString = NSMutableString(string:"Hello, playground")

var newStr = str

newStr.append(". Hello")

print(str)
print(newStr)
```

Then you will get the output

> Hello, playground. Hello
>
> Hello, playground. Hello

Since you are modifying the one object that is referenced by both variables.

Answer (score 3):

> Reference type means if we change the value of reference it will reflect in the original value too.

Yes, that is true. However in your code `newStr = "hello"` you are not **changing the value of reference type**. As Paulw11 pointed out in the comment `newStr = "hello"` assigns `newStr` as a reference to a different constant string.

Let's say that `str` is pointing to and address 0xAAAA.

`var newStr = str` causes `newStr` to point to 0xAAAA.

`newStr = "hello"` now points to another address of the constant string `hello`. Lets say the address is 0xBBBB

As you can see `str` is pointing to 0xAAAA and `newStr` is pointing to 0xBBBB, hence they are bound to produce different results.