# Pass a variable reference to a instance property

Tags: swift, pass-by-reference

I want to make sure that if you update the original variable, the instance property is also updated.

```
class Sample {

    var number: Int
    
    init(number: inout Int) {
        self.number = number
    }
}

var number = 0
let sample = Sample(number: &number)

number = 1
print(sample.number)    // 0
```

In the above code, the instance property has not been updated.
How do I fix it?

Comment: An `inout` function parameter has a value that is passed in to the function, is modified by the function, and is passed back out of the function to replace the original value. It doesn't create some sort of permanent binding to the variable passed into function. `Int` is a value type. You can try to use i.e. `NSNumber` instead, which is a class, hence a reference type.

Comment: Value type and reference type in Swift https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44195908/value-type-and-reference-type-in-swift

Comment: How to get the reference of a value type in Swift? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138449/how-to-get-the-reference-of-a-value-type-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

`inout` parameters work like this ([source](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#ID545)):

> 1. When the function is called, the value of the argument is copied.
> 2. In the body of the function, the copy is modified.
> 3. When the function returns, the copy’s value is assigned to the original argument.

This is not "pass by reference" in the C or C++ sense. You are not passing a "reference" to the initialiser. The compiler can optimise `inout` parameters to use the same memory address for both the original and the copy, but at that point, you know too much :)

So what you are trying to do doesn't really make sense. You seem to want `Sample.number` to store a "reference" to the `Int` that you passed in, but that's not possible, because `Int` is a value type.

You have to make your own wrapper class for `Int`:

```
class IntWrapper : ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral, CustomStringConvertible {
    var wrapped: Int
    
    required init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        wrapped = value
    }
    
    var description: String { wrapped.description }
}

class Sample {

    let number: IntWrapper
    
    init(number: IntWrapper) {
        self.number = number
    }
}

let number: IntWrapper = 0
let sample = Sample(number: number)

number.wrapped = 1
print(sample.number)
```